# (Yocto Raspberrypi) How to write the file with estension .tar.xz into micro sdCard?

Tags: yocto, meta-raspberrypi

I'm building a custom image-qt5 using yocto tools. Once the build terminates, there is a file named `qt5-image-raspberrypi2.tar.xz` in the folder `...build/tmp/deploy/images/raspberrepy2/`.

How can we write to sdcard for the raspberrypi?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague.

If you were just looking at writing the `qt5-image-raspberrypi2.tar.xz` file to your SD card; you can use the command: [dd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) to achieve this.  Given that it is a tar ball you will need to first handle this before writing it to the sd card.

Example (where /dev/sdX is your mounted SD card on your computer):

```
tar -xzOf qt5-image-raspberrypi2.tar.xz | dd of=/dev/sdX bs=1M
```

If you already have an sdcard image that has been generated within Yocto and you wish to include the `qt5-image-raspberrypi2.tar.xz` tar ball to the sdcard image, then you will need to modify your recipe to add the file to your `SRC_URI` list.

Example:

```
SRC_URI += '$(DEPLOY_DIR}/qt5-image-raspberrypi2.tar.xz'
```

Replace the tar ball file name with appropriate variables which are used when generating the name, or you could hard code it, as above.